# Android vibrate on checkbox

Tags: java, android, android-activity, vibration

I want to built a simple app which vibrates on click on the checkbox and stops after another click:

currently it looks like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        final CheckBox vibrateCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkPowerStrong);

        if(vibrateCheckBox.isChecked()) {
            while(vibrateCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                vibrator.vibrate(1000);
            }
        } else {
            vibrator.cancel();
        }

    }
}
```

But I do get an error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not
>   available to Activities before onCreate()

I gave the manifest the permission to vibrate:

how to solve this

Comment: Maybe add a change listener to the check box? Because this tells it to vibrate as soon as the app starts, not when the box is checked

Comment: You shouldn't be getting that Exception with that code.

Comment: Could you show me a snippet on how you exactly mean it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It exactly works what you want. Do something like this

```
final Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
final CheckBox vibrateCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkPowerStrong);

final Handler handler = new Handler();

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        vibrator.vibrate(1000);
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

vibrateCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
           if(vibrateCheckBox.isChecked()) {
               handler.postDelayed(r, 100);
           } else {
               handler.removeCallbacks(r);
               vibrator.cancel();
           }

       }
   }
);
```

Comment: Could you explain what exactly my mistake was

Comment: Your while statement was never be false not only that it is start endless try to check your checkbox that may cause your application hang.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

vibrateCheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkPowerStrong);
vibrateCheckBox.setChecked(false);
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);



vibrateCheckBox .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked)
        {
             v.vibrate(500);     // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
         }else
         {
            v.cancel();
         }
    }
});

}
```

Add permissions in **Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

**How to Vibrate Indefinitely**

```
// Get instance of Vibrator from current Context
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

// Start without a delay
// Vibrate for 100 milliseconds
// Sleep for 1000 milliseconds
long[] pattern = {0, 100, 1000};

// The '0' here means to repeat indefinitely
// '0' is actually the index at which the pattern keeps repeating from (the start)
// To repeat the pattern from any other point, you could increase the index, e.g. '1'
v.vibrate(pattern, 0);
```

When you're ready to stop the vibration, just call the `cancel()` method:

```
v.cancel();
```

**How to use Vibration Patterns**

```
If you want a more bespoke vibration, you can attempt to create your own vibration patterns:

// Get instance of Vibrator from current Context
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

// Start without a delay
// Each element then alternates between vibrate, sleep, vibrate, sleep...
long[] pattern = {0, 100, 1000, 300, 200, 100, 500, 200, 100};

// The '-1' here means to vibrate once, as '-1' is out of bounds in the pattern array
v.vibrate(pattern, -1);
```